# Can we use Flink instead of SQOOP to offload a RDBMS tables into HDFS? Could it be more efficient and faster?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

1. I am looking to offload a number of tables from RDBMS sources like
   Oracle table to HDFS. Can Flink be faster than using Sqoop for this Job.
2. Any suggestions as to what setting for the source parallelism
   should be. Does JDBC connector in Flink automatically read in
   parallel?
3. If yes, does it automatically able to avoid duplicate
   reading(because of parallelism) or should we do something for this
   to happen?